# What strengthenings of measurability do the Mostowski collapses of ultrapowers possess?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, ultrapowers

What strengthenings of measurability does the Mostowski collapse of the ultrapowers possess?

Ok, I already posted this question, but a couple of notational errors and assumptions were made in the previous version. Hopefully, this new equivalent version will be better understood.

Let $U$ be a nonprinciple $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter over $\lambda$.
Let $\pi_U(f)$ for a function $f$ with domain $\lambda$ be defined as follows:
$$\pi_U(f)=\{\pi_U(g):\{\alpha<\lambda:g(\alpha)\in f(\alpha)\}\in U\}$$

Let $M$ be $\{\pi_U(f):\mathrm{Dom}(f)=\lambda\}$. Finally, let $\lambda_0=\lambda$ and:
$$\lambda_{n+1}=|\{\pi_U(f):\{\alpha<\lambda:g(\alpha)\in \lambda_n\}\in U\}|$$

**Then, which of the following are always true:**

- If $\lambda$ is $\theta$-strong, then $V_\theta\subset M$.
- If $\lambda$ is $\theta$-supercompact, then $M^\theta\subset M$.
- If $\lambda$ is $n$-superstrong, then $V_{\lambda_n}\subset M$.
- If $\lambda$ is $n$-huge, then $M^{\lambda_n}\subset M$.

Comment: This question is oddly phrased. How could $V_\alpha$ be a subset of the ultrapower anyway? Since the ultrapower is a collection of equivalence classes. Most sets are not equivalence classes.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. When we say $M^\theta\subset M$ for an ultrapower $M$, we mean that $M$ is closed under $\theta$ sequences in a way that makes sense with thinking about $\langle M,\in^M\rangle$ as a structure in the language of set theory, which is of course not literally the same as saying it is closed under $\theta$-sequences. When $M$ is well-founded, as it is with complete ultrafilters, then this amounts to saying the corresponding thing about the Mostowski collapse of $M$, which trivializes the question. Set theorists usually identify the ultrapower with its collapse.

Comment: @AsafKaragila $MO$ is not the ultrapower, rather the Mostowski collapse of it.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins $M$ is a transitive inner model such that $j:V\rightarrow M$ is an elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$. $M$ has no relation to $MO$. Am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: Maybe it would be advisable to read again what people mean when they talk about ultrapower construction in set theory. Perhaps introductory books or papers.

Comment: I *think* what you are asking is whether many (or all?) of the reflection properties captured by large cardinal embeddings can be realized by ultrapowers by ultrafilters. Is this correct? And if so, do you want to restrict the carrier set of the ultrafilter ($\kappa$-complete ultrafilters on $\kappa$? Or on $\mathcal{P}_\kappa(\lambda)$? Or something else?)

Comment: Ah, good idea Miha. It isn't about Mostowski collapses at all. I would phrase the question as:  which large cardinal embeddings can be realized by ultrapowers? And then one should say what kinds of ultrapowers one is talking about.

Comment: At first, I read the question as asking whether the existence of one $j$ with critical point $\kappa$ and with some property would imply that all ultrapowers by $\kappa$-complete non-principal ultrafilters would have the same property. But that reading doesn't match your claim about measurability being an example. Every measurable cardinal $\kappa$ has a $\kappa$-complete non-principal ultrafilter in whose ultrapower $\kappa$ is no longer measurable (equivalently: minimal in Mitchell order).

Comment: I'll just delete the question, it doesn't seem like my point was broadcasked properly.

Comment: You can't delete a question with an upvoted answer...

Comment: By the way, I *know* that $MO$ denotes the Mostowski collapse. I am just sufficiently familiar with the fact that is stated in most introductory places: where we consider ultrapowers, we identify a well-founded ultrapower with its transitive collapse. And otherwise, many of these questions are oddly placed (as I explain in my first comment).

Comment: Ok, I edited the question and replaced it with an equivalent statement.

Comment: So, with your edits, you really seem to be asking what kind of closure properties the ultrapower by an ultrafilter on $\lambda$ might posses. Joel already answered that in his post below; such ultrapowers never contain $V_{\lambda+2}$ (and are thus not closed under $2^\lambda$-sequences), but if GCH fails at $\lambda$, they might be closed under $\lambda^+$-sequences, and more.

Comment: @MihaHabič I know, but to not confuse the people who may read my question, I edited the question to be more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's adopt Miha's interpretation of your question: which kinds of large cardinal properties can be witnessed by ultrapower embeddings?

Here, there are a variety of things one can say.

If one allows $\kappa$-complete measures on arbitrary sets, then basically all the usual large cardinal properties can be witnessed with suitably chosen ultrapower embeddings. For example, supercompactness embeddings $j:V\to M$ are ultrapowers by normal fine measures on $P_\kappa\theta$, and these kinds of embeddings are also $\alpha$-strong, when $\beth_\alpha\leq\theta$.

Hugeness and almost hugeness are also witnessed by ultrapower embeddings on a suitable set, so this means that (assuming appropriate consistency strength), we can realize all the properties on your list with ultrapower embeddings.

But meanwhile, one cannot expect to *define* the various extender-based large cardinal notions in ZFC using only ultrapowers. For example, it is relatively consistent that $\kappa$ is strong, but for large enough $\alpha$, there is no ultrapower embedding $j:V\to M$ by a measure on any set for which $V_\alpha\subset M$.

If you mean to allow only ultrapowers by measures on $\kappa$ itself, then much of those embeddings are not possible.

- No ultrapower embedding by a measure on $\kappa$ can realize $\kappa+2$ strongness, since $M_{j(\kappa)}$ will have size $2^\kappa$ in $V$ and therefore cannot contain all of $V_{\kappa+2}$.
- In particular, no ultrapower embedding by a measure on $\kappa$ can realize $2^\kappa$-supercompactness, for then it would realize $\kappa+2$-strongness.
- Meanwhile, there is a kind of border right at that level. There is an interesting theorem of Woodin showing how to make the least measurable cardinal also a little supercompact, and in that model, we get that the $\kappa^+$-supercompactness of $\kappa$ is witnessed by a normal ultrapower on $\kappa$. Necessarily, by the previous observations, $\kappa^+<2^\kappa$ in this model.
  (Arthur Apter also has some work on this.)

That last example would be perhaps one of the most interesting situations fitting under the umbrella of this interpretation of your question.

Comment: Although $\theta$-supercompactness can be witnessed by an ultrapower as you said, full supercompactness seems to need a lot of utrapowers --- or am I missing something here.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, being supercompact is properly a $\Pi_3$ statement. It cannot be $\Sigma_2$, because then the existence of a supercompact cardinal would reflect below the least supercompact cardinal, leading to big problems.

Comment: I was interpreting the question differently, and more simply: which large cardinal properties can be realized by ultrapower embeddings, in place of the arbitrary embeddings one might state. If you define $\kappa$ is supercompact to be: for every $\theta$ there is $j:V\to M$ with critical point $\kappa$ and $M^\theta\subset M$, then indeed it is equivalent to also insist that $j$ is an ultrapower embedding. In the case of strong, etc., this is not an equivalence, but meanwhile it is relatively consistent that strongness is witnessed by ultrapowers, e.g., by supercompactness ultrapowers.

Comment: Aha, @JoelDavidHamkins, this new comment that you have provided is precisely my question. Thank you for taking the time to understand my poorly written question.